# Laravel get post categories with pivot table as BelongsToMany()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

in my database i have `contents_categories` and `content` table with `BelongsToMany()` relation ship

`Contents`:

```
class Contents extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contents';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ContentCategories::class);
    }
}
```

`ContentCategories`:

```
class ContentCategories extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contents_categories';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function contents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Contents::class);
    }
}
```

using this code to store data in `contents` table with selected multiple category work fine and that can be save into database and pivot table as `content_categories_contents`

```
public function store(RequestContents $request)
{
    $data = Contents::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'lang' => $request->_language,
        'type' => $request->type,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'featured_images' => '',
        'visit' => 0,
    ]);

    $data->categories()->attach($request->categories);
}
```

[image]

now! unfortunately when i try to use this code to get categories of content i dont have them in result:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $content = Contents::find($id);
    $selected_categories = $content->categories();
    dd($selected_categories);
}
```

result:

```
BelongsToMany {#208 ▼
  #table: "content_categories_contents"
  #foreignPivotKey: "contents_id"
  #relatedPivotKey: "content_categories_id"
  #parentKey: "id"
  #relatedKey: "id"
  #relationName: "categories"
  #pivotColumns: []
  #pivotWheres: []
  #pivotWhereIns: []
  #pivotCreatedAt: null
  #pivotUpdatedAt: null
  #using: null
  #accessor: "pivot"
  #query: Builder {#217 ▼
    #query: Builder {#209 ▶}
    #model: ContentCategories {#213 ▼
      #table: "contents_categories"
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: false
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: []
      #original: []
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
    }
    #eagerLoad: []
    #localMacros: []
    #onDelete: null
    #passthru: array:11 [▶]
    #scopes: []
    #removedScopes: []
  }
  #parent: Contents {#218 ▼
    #table: "contents"
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #fillable: []
  }
  #related: ContentCategories {#213 ▶}
}
```

Comment: Open this collection data in your result: `#related: ContentCategories {#213 ▶}` Is it empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because that method you defined is returning exactly what you have defined it to return a `BelongsToMany` object. These are builder type objects so you can query the relationship. They are no the result of it.

You are expecting the loaded relationship it would seem. You would have to query the relationship yourself, or hit the "dynamic property" for the relationship which will load it if it isn't already loaded and return the result.

```
$model->categories();   // returns what you defined it to return
$model->categories()->where(...)->get();

$model->categories;   // loaded relationship via dynamic property
```

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Relationship Methods vs Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)